# Making simple top and left navigation with simple iframe and CSS

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am having some trouble with this for some reason... I've been using old school html frames forever and decided I should start using iframes for easier javascript integration... I need a top nav and a left nav with content filling the rest of the page... Tell me what I'm doing wrong!!

**Original**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<iframe style="display:block; width:100%; height:50px" 
        src="navTop.html" name="iframeTop" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
<iframe style="display:inline; overflow:hidden; width=10%; height=100%;" 
        src="navLeft.html" name="iframeLeft" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
<iframe style="display:block; float:right; width=90%; height=100%" 
        src="content.html" name="iframeCenter" scrolling="auto" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
<noframes></noframes>
</html>
```

I am sure its something really simple that I am missing. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I started trying to accomplish this with div's and css... This is where I am... It's not working still... Help!!!

**CSS**:

```
<style>
        body {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
        }
        #topNavigation div {
                background-color:100719;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-left:0px;
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
        }
        #leftNavigation div {
                background-color:100719;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                margin-top:50px;
                margin-left:0px;
                width:400px;
                height:100%;
        }
        #displayContent div {
                background-color:100719;
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                margin-top:50px;
                margin-left:400px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
        }
</style>
```

**DIVS**:

```
<body>
        <div id="topNavigation">
                <iframe src="navTop.html" 
                        style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" 
                        name="navTop" 
                        scrolling="no" 
                        frameborder="0" 
                        marginheight="0px" 
                        marginwidth="0px">
                </iframe>
        </div>  
        <div id="leftNavigation">
                <iframe src="navLeft.html" 
                        style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" 
                        name="navLeft" 
                        scrolling="no" 
                        frameborder="0" 
                        marginheight="0px" 
                        marginwidth="0px">
                </iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="displayContent">
                <iframe src="content.html" 
                        style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" 
                        name="content" 
                        scrolling="no" 
                        frameborder="0" 
                        marginheight="0px" 
                        marginwidth="0px">
                </iframe>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; line-height:0; height:100%">
    <iframe src="navTop.html" 
            style="margin:0px; padding:0px; line-height:0; width:100%; height:8%;" 
            name="navTop" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
            <iframe src="navLeft.html" 
            style="margin:0px; padding:0px; line-height:0; width:10%; height:100%; float:left"
            name="navLeft" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
    <iframe src="content.html" 
            style="margin:0px; padding:0px; line-height:0; width:90%; height:100%; float:right"
            name="content" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
```